# Get the list of files from document directory contains same name but with different extensions.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the list of files belongs to same name . 
Below are the files saved in document directory .
start.pdf , start.png ,  start_1.drawingpad , start_1.imagepad and other files like second.pdf , second.png .....

here .pdf , .png , .DrawingPad , .imagepad belongs to one set .

I need to list out these set , start.pdf , png , start_1.drawingpad and imagepad from document directory.

Comment: How is `start.pdf` part of the `start_1.drawingpad` set?  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Below answer worked for me .

Comment: That's a poor solution because the naming scheme being used is ill thought-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,This will result the array of values which contains matched string.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *renameArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

NSString *strprdicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS '%@'",@"start"];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:strprdicate];
renameArray =  [renameArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"files array %@", renameArray);
```

Make sure you should pass input string in '' if input is a string for NSPredicate.

Comment: What about the file-set `restarted.pdf` etc?

Comment: what is restarted.pdf ?

Comment: I got the list of files contains same name .